# Object deserialization in release build on android

Tags: java, android, release

I'm developing an android app which has to communicate with server (both written in java). To communicate, I use custom serialized objects (ObjectStream's). The thing is when I build my android app with debug configuration everything works fine, but if I use release configuration I'm getting following error during deserialization on the server side.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: d.a.b.d.d

How can I fix this issue? Is it even possible?

Comment: that error is likely caused by proguard. Try `-keep`-ing the classes you are sending in proguard configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your `/app/proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

This should prevent proguard from name mangling the Serializable classes.

Comment: Now it recognizes class names but serialVersionUID does not match.
java.io.InvalidClassException: local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4153259734270116860, local class serialVersionUID = -6717172171618781649

Comment: You might need to set serialVersionUID on the server and client side. Otherwise, it is generated by the compiler.